# Remote file upload help needed

Tags: php, file, variables, file-upload

This is my normal file upload code.

> HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
      <input name="theFile" type="file" />
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

> PHP Variables to receive file

```
$fileName = $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
$fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
```

Now i would like to use remote upload.

So i created a form like this

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=$self?>">
<input type="text" name="file[]"  size="45" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" accesskey="s"></p>
</form>
```

I have to enter file url in the above form. When i submit the form i want the file file details store in these variables `$fileName,$fileTempName`

I don't want them to store locally. I'm trying to use those variables in amazon s3 upload. Could you guys help me?. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.remotepage.com/upload.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'])); 
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Does this drain cpu/memory bandwidth of any of the servers?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make remote upload but wihthout option to reupload it to your server? Why don't you just send your form to your uploading place & proccess it there? It's fastest and the best solution..

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Basically i need to upload many videos to amazon s3. Downloading it to my local PC and uploading again to amazon s3 is much time consuming. I got amazon s3 class [from here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/) In that tutorial they explained about uploading from PC to amazon s3. But I need remote upload. Its like i have to get files using curl and assigning it the variables i mentioned above. There after amazon s3 class will take care of it.You have good rep.So i hope u can help me.Thx