# Remote Server File Upload Via PHP

Tags: php, file, post

I have two servers, one with my website, the other for storage. I'm trying to have a page where someone can upload a file to the storage server, I'm hoping to use a form post to get it there. I've written a very simple bit of code to troubleshoot this and am having a little trouble. It works fine if I change the action to a .php that saves it on the same server, but when I change it to my storage server, it fails to upload and shows me the "else" echo that my fail failed to upload.

the HTML on my web server:

```
<form action="http://storageServer/upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP on my storage server:

```
<?php
$folder = "files/";
$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

The .php is in the html folder with the "files" folder.

Any reason the file isn't making it to the server that you can see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This topic answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963742/remote-file-upload-help-needed)

As suggested, you could use CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.remotepage.com/upload.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'])); 
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I was trying to do it without cURL. Is it possible the way I was working on it, or am I going to have to add something like cURL to the mix?

Comment: Perhaps you could process the request on the server you're uploading to?

Comment: @Milksnake12 cURL tends to be packaged with most PHP installations.

Comment: @arxanas, he's reluctant to use cURL.

Comment: If I have to to use cURL thats fine, more was just trying to do it without. I've done a little reading on it now and how would I implement the code you gave? Would you still use a form action to get to the php page on the storage server?

Comment: @Milksnake12 All this code does is post to a PHP script on the storage server itself. This code is not mine, so you'll have to refer to the original thread which is the hyperlink at the start.

Comment: @SarahLasonia need close array, $_FILES['theFile'**]** - you need add **]**