# Use an external url to upload images with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to change the upload_path using an external url.
Instead of using the script below

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/shop_images';
```

I need to upload the images in a different url like this

```
$url = 'www.mydomain.com/images/upload';
$config['upload_path'] = $url;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the correct way, However you can try the below method:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.remotepage.com/upload.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CUROPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['theFile'] ['tmp_name'])); 
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

> Also, you need to have a php script on the remote server that should
>   allow(permit) you to upload file to the desired location on the remote server as it could be a security concern.

You can refer: [Remote Server File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232745/1295349)