# Symfony2 file upload handling with multiple servers ant load balancer

Tags: symfony, file-upload

My Symfony2 application is hosted in 1 servers `app1` and `app2`, load balancer routing request to `app1/app2` accordings to the load on server.

I'm need store uploaded files only on app1, how I can do this using Symfony `UploadedFile()`.

In documentation I don't find any possibility to pass to UploadedFile hostname ?

What is simplest way to store all uploaded file with `UploadedFile()` in `app1`

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this could be to have single place for file uploads on the server that both apps point to. Just have each app link to there.
E.g
*app1/src/web/uploads -> /var/uploads*
*app2/src/web/uploads -> /var/uploads*

Comment: I'm not have possibility to have mounted dirs, just want upload to app1 from app1 and app2 and read files only from app1

Comment: @Wizard you question states that your are on one server, so why can't you define the upload location in your parameters.yml, so all files get saved there. You can use the same location when requesting to read a file. Ref Creating an Uploader Service - http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html (about half way down) or use the VichUploaderBundle bundle which will let you do the same (look at the Namers-related section)

Comment: no applications are on multiple servers app1 and app2

Comment: If you can determine what app server you on, then if app2 use an event to move the file to app1 using cURL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963742/remote-file-upload-help-needed and